# why using (LINQ to XML) ,having simple readxml and writexml methods of DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, linq-to-xml, data-access-layer

why using (LINQ to XML)complex classes as we have simple methods in  dataset class (readxml,writexml) that have all features in LINQ to XML

Comment: deferred execution for one

Comment: What is complex and what is simple is very personal... A lot of people would consider LINQ version much simple and flexible than dataset ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataset is able to read/write only very small subset of XML. LINQ to XML have no such restriction.

Comment: how small can it deal with ?